# How do I make a Pop-Up Menu from my Contacts Group names, using AppleScript and Numbers?

Tags: applescript, contacts

Please note: The site is not letting me post this question unless I incorrectly format it i.e. the two middle sections of "code" which aren't actually code. I've done my best to edit it, to fix it, and I apologise if the formatting is poor.

I’ve found and adjusted two scripts, which run, individually. This is my first AppleScript project, and I’d like help **joining them together to MAKE ONE SCRIPT.**

**I want Script 2 to use the result from Script 1.**
e.g. *set menuItems to (Script 1 Result names)*

I made a dummy testGroup in my Contacts. The Pop-Up Menu only needs the names.  I will use the corresponding email addresses later, in another script.

I hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Script 1**

```
--returns Contacts testGroup’s names and email addresses

set myList to ""
tell application "Contacts" to repeat with p in people in group "testGroup"
    if emails of p is {} then
        set e to ""
    else
        set e to value of email 1 of p
    end if
    set myList to myList & name of p
end repeat
```

Script 1 Result needs parsing...

```
"Joe BloggsMolly MousePeter Pan"
```

to this...

```
{"Joe Bloggs", "Molly Mouse", "Peter Pan"}
```

so I can use it in Script 2 menuItems below.

**Script 2** MUST use names from Script 1 Result, like this

```
-- Make Pop-Up Menu in Numbers spreadsheet which is already open.

set menuItems to {"Joe Bloggs", "Molly Mouse", "Peter Pan"}

tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell the first table of the active sheet of document 1
        tell cell "A3"
            set value to item 1 of menuItems
            set the format to pop up menu
        end tell
    end tell
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Numbers"
        set frontmost to true
        tell window 1
            click radio button "Cell" of radio group 1
            repeat with i from 2 to (count menuItems)
                click button 1 of group 1 of scroll area -1
                keystroke (item i of menuItems)
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first script is going through the items of a list list to create a string, while the second script is just wanting the list.  Since the Contacts application will give you a list of names, the first script isn't needed at all - the `menuItems` of the second script can just be set with:

```
tell application "Contacts" to set menuItems to the name of people in group "testGroup"
```

Comment: Thanks @red_menace.Tried this in many places, with and without first script, and either get errors (various) or ScriptEditor says running, and won't stop, unless I force quit it. First script seems necessary for specifying the particular cell. Also tried it using tell application _process_ Contacts...

Comment: All the first script does is make a string (which you don't use) from the contact names.  I tested the second script as written with just the new statement setting the menuItems  (if you look at it, it is just a list of the names), and it worked as intended with my contacts list.  The first Numbers tell statement sets the cell, then the second System Events tell statement populates the menu.  A sheet needs to already exist.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but have no idea where to put the statement, so that it works...

Comment: OK got it! I put your statement at the beginning of the second script, and it works perfectly. ( It's strange that it doesn't need an **end tell** ) Thanks @red_menace - I appreciate your time.

Comment: Several statements such as `if` and `tell` have simple (single line) as well as compound (multiple line) forms, e.g. `if this then that` and `tell this to that`.